# Reflecting object internals in type signature

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda-fantasy

I'm diving into FP in js (I'm newbbie to FP) and I faced a little "problem" describing remaining arguments of curried functions, wrapped into Functors

Let's say we have the following curried situation:

```
const makeApiCallFuture = curry((path, user, password, params) => Future(...));
const makeApiCallIoFuture = (path) => IO(makeApiCallFuture(path));

// And so on, let's imagine that each next function reduces one more arg
const someFunc = compose(ap(userIO), makeApiCallIoFuture);
```

I would like to indicate for each function, how many curried arguments it still expects, even if those functions are wrapped in Functors, to avoid any confusions in development.

For example, for `makeApiCallFuture` we can write `String -> String -> String -> Object -> Future` which is pretty clear.

Next function `makeApiCallIoFuture` reduces number of curried arguments and wraps the rest of the function into the `IO`.

The type signature becomes `makeApiCallIoFuture :: String -> IO` or maybe even `makeApiCallIoFuture :: String -> IO a` which is I think not clear enough, as function in IO is still curried and developers will need to dive into the code to understand how many arguments they still need to pass.

So, my question is - is it possible to indicate such situations using the type signatures? Maybe it's possible to write something like:

```
makeApiCallIoFuture :: String -> IO (String -> String -> Object -> Future)

someFunc :: String -> IO (String -> Object -> Future)
```

or even more verbose:

```
makeApiCallIoFuture :: Path -> IO (User -> Password -> Params -> Future)
    User = String
    Password = String
    Params = Object

someFunc :: User -> IO (Password -> Params -> Future)
    User = String
    Password = String
    Params = Object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The type signature becomes `makeApiCallIoFuture :: String -> IO`

No. `IO` expects a type parameter, alone it is an invalid (or: incomplete) type.

> or maybe even `makeApiCallIoFuture :: String -> IO a` which is I think not clear enough

What is `a`? Your `makeApiCallIoFuture` is not generic over `a`, so leaving the `a` type unspecified is wrong.

> is it possible to indicate such situations using the type signatures? Maybe it's possible to write something like:
>
> ```
> makeApiCallIoFuture :: String -> IO (String -> String -> Object -> Future)
> ```

Yes, exactly this is the only correct solution.